# Extract data from book(.indb) created with InDesign?

Tags: ruby, parsing, import, export, adobe-indesign

I need to create fb2 and epub files from data stored in InDesign`s files. How can i extract text, chapters, titles, images and other from a .indd or .indb file? 
Maybe exists some gem? Or can somebody point me in the right direction where i could find solution of my problem?

Comment: those two formats are binaries and unless a close partnership with Adobe, I don't think you can "read" a indd without opening it actually.